# Not able Publish RestFul webservices Using Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I am trying to build simple webservices using **Java, Rest Webservices(Jersey), Glass fish**. project is successfully deploying in server without any errors, but when i access resources in browser it is giving **404-Not Found Error**.

**My resources class:**

```
package org.student.services;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;  
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;  
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  



@Path("/ConversionService")  
public class FeetToInchAndInchToFeetConversionService {  
     @GET  
     @Path("/InchToFeet/{i}")  
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)  
      public String convertInchToFeet(@PathParam("i") int i) {  


    int inch=i;  
    double feet = 0;  
    feet =(double) inch/12;  

    return "<InchToFeetService>"  
    + "<Inch>" + inch + "</Inch>"  
      + "<Feet>" + feet + "</Feet>"  
     + "</InchToFeetService>";  
  }  

  @Path("/FeetToInch/{f}")  
  @GET  
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)  
  public String convertFeetToInch(@PathParam("f") int f) {  
   int inch=0;  
      int feet = f;  
      inch = 12*feet;  

      return "<FeetToInchService>"  
        + "<Feet>" + feet + "</Feet>"  
        + "<Inch>" + inch + "</Inch>"  
        + "</FeetToInchService>";  
  }
```

}

**And Web.xml is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"> 
   <display-name>StudentPortal</display-name>  
  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>    
    <init-param>  
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
      <param-value>org.student.services</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

using following Url with https//
mylocalhost:port/StudentPortal/rest/ConversionService/InchToFeet/2

Please Someone point what i am doing wrong

Comment: please call service like this --> warName/rest/ConversionService/InchToFeet/100

Comment: What's the url you use in browser when you try to use ConversionService? Is it simply http://localhost:port/rest/ConversionService? Do you use Spring Framework as well in your project?

Comment: I am using https// mylocalhost:port/StudentPortal/rest/ConversionService/InchToFeet/2, no i am not using springframework